# How to Update main table from second table with multiple same values in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update my main table by comparing it with another table that contains the same fields but have the daily values. The second table contains multiple records for same person too. (no primary key in this table)

My query executes fine but it stops when it finds the first match and doesn't scan rest of the table.

```
update crates as a, t23042019 as b set a.srsb=a.srsb+b.srsb, a.srsc=a.srsc+b.srsc, a.hfc=a.hfc+b.hfc, a.mix=a.mix+b.mix where a.name=b.name;
```

crates table

```
name   srsb srsc hfc mix
hitesh 5    5    5   5
raman  2    3    4   1
```

t23042019 table

```
name   srsb srsc hfc mix
raman  1    -2   0   1
hitesh 2     2   2   2
hitesh -5 0 0 -2
raman -1 0 0 0
```

Expected result after the query

```
crates table
name   srsb srsc hfc mix
hitesh 2    7    7   5
raman  2    1    4   2
```

Query result

crates table

```
name   srsb srsc hfc mix
hitesh 7    7    7   7 
raman  3    1    4   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below:

```
UPDATE crates a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT name, SUM(srsb) AS srsb, SUM(srsc) AS srsc, SUM(hfc) AS hfc, SUM(mix) AS mix
FROM t23042019
GROUP BY name) s
ON a.name=s.name
SET a.srsb=a.srsb+s.srsb,
...
```

Comment: True but can you explain why op's query does not work?

Comment: It gives an error 1054, unknown column s.name in on clause.

Comment: Seems you tried right after my post. I did an immediate editing after posting the answer because I forgot the grouping. Can you try again?

Comment: It did work. Thanks !
However it is adding 1 more to the last result

It is showing the result as
name   srsb srsc hfc mix
hitesh 7    7    7   7 
raman  3    1    4   3

instead of 
name   srsb srsc hfc mix
hitesh 7    7    7   7 
raman  3    1    4   2

Comment: @P.Salmon for UPDATE with joins, if more than one row matches, only one matching row is expected. It just takes the last one to do the update. Some RDBMS even throw exception if multiple rows match.

Comment: @HiteshSethi Please double check your query/data. I can't think of any reason why one is added to the person for the last column

Comment: @PeterHe thanks a lot ! 
Need one more help... I want to insert the result of the inner query in the crates table if the name in t23042019 is not present in crates table

insert into crates (name,srsb,srsc,hfc,mix) 
SELECT name, SUM(srsb) AS srsb, SUM(srsc) AS srsc, SUM(hfc) AS hfc, SUM(mix) AS mix
FROM t26042019
GROUP BY name;

what should come in the where clause.

Comment: You can put WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM crates c WHERE c,name= t.name) before GROUP BY (give an alias t to the table t26042019)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! help much appreciated.

Comment: @PeterHe I have just added a date column to t26042019 table. It contains the current date. I want to update the crates table as above but with the current date's record only. I added the Where clause at the end of this query but it shows an error Unknown column.

UPDATE crates a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT name, SUM(srsb) AS srsb, SUM(srsc) AS srsc, SUM(hfc) AS hfc, SUM(mix) AS mix
FROM t23042019
GROUP BY name) s
ON a.name=s.name
SET a.srsb=a.srsb+s.srsb,
Where s.date='30042019'

Comment: Add Where s.date='30042019' to the subquery before GROUP BY name

Comment: @PeterHe 
it still gives the same error Unknown column

Comment: I meant Where date='30042019', not Where s.date='30042019'